# get the dominant colors in multi-channel image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, deep-learning, semantic-segmentation

I have a Unet segmentation model that predicts a 5 channel image with 5 colors:

```
0, 255, 0,     green   label 0
0, 0, 255,     blue    label 1
255, 255, 0,   yellow  label 2                   
255, 0, 0,      red    label 3
255, 255, 255   white  label 4
```

The model prediction gives a 5 channel image with a shape of 128,128,5,
as shown in the image, the training image with 5 channel predicted mask:

[image]

I want to find the color in each channel so that I find the most dominant color in the image and find the predicted label.

I tried this:

```
predicted_img=model.predict(image[:,:,:])[0]
print('predicted_img shape ',predicted_img.shape)

colors, counts = np.unique(predicted_img.reshape(-1,5), return_counts = True, axis = 0)
colors=counts.argmax()

print('colors   ',colors )
```

But it is not showing the colors in each channel, just gives a 0

```
predicted_img shape (128, 128, 5)
colors 0
```

how can I get the colors in each channel in the format of [255,255,255]

Comment: numpy, argmax over axis 2

Comment: after reshaping the 5 channel image the shape is (16384, 5), axis=2 is gives an error

Comment: oh well, axis=1 then. you get what I mean.

Comment: I'm trying to understand about the segmentation model's output. You've mentioned that there's a `segmentation model that predicts a 5 channel image with 5 colors`. I'm not clear about how a color value can be derived from this 5-channel output (assuming a color is a 3D value). Would you mind detailing your problem setup a bit? Maybe some information about the training labels (and how do you get a color from a such 5-channel label) would help.

Comment: The input to the model is an image of prostate cancer ( see the updated question above), with a 5 channel mask image as the class of the image (0 to 4) based on the most dominant color. The model predicts the output as 5 channel image, I want to find out the most dominant color in all the 5 channels to have the output class of the test image. I want to apply cohen kappa based on the actual and predicted labels of the mask images.